# How to make react-hook-form require 1 checkbox?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, react-hook-form

I have a Checkbox component which works fine, until I had a Yup schema:

```
const Checkbox = React.forwardRef(
  (
    {
      label,
      name,
      value,
      onChange,
      defaultChecked,
      errors,
      onBlur,
      ...rest
    }: any,
    forwardedRef: any
  ) => {
    return (
      <div className="grow w-full">
        <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          value={value}
          name={name}
          onChange={onChange}
          onBlur={onBlur}
          ref={forwardedRef}
          {...rest}
        />
        {errors && <p className="error">{errors.message}</p>}
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

Which I use like this:

```
export default function App() {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    register,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    resolver: yupResolver(schema)
  });

  const onSubmit = (data: any) => {
    console.log("clicked");
    console.log(errors, "errors");
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Checkbox
        {...register("name", { required: "This is required." })}
        name={"name"}
        value={"test"}
        label={"Test"}
        errors={errors.name}
      />
      <Checkbox
        {...register("name", { required: "This is required." })}
        name={"name"}
        value={"test"}
        label={"Test"}
        errors={errors.name}
      />
      <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  );
}
```

When I go to submit my form, I get the following error:

```
name must be a `array` type, but the final value was: `null` (cast from the value `false`). If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as `.nullable()`
```

[Here's my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/optimistic-bouman-w8u18z?file=/src/App.tsx)

[Here's the code I followed](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-l3io1m?file=src%2FApp.js) to get me to this stage - to me it looks the same? Can't see where I've gone wrong here

Comment: It works when you have multiple checkbox components with a name of `"name"`, otherwise `name` doesn't need to be an array in your schema if you only have one checkbox.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for your reply. In my actual code I have the checkboxes being generated  through a map function, but I still get the error despite each Checkbox sharing a name value. I'll update the OP to show what I mean

Comment: OP and Sandbox updated - error still exists

Comment: I can't see the error anymore in your new Sandbox. I selected both checkboxes and then clicked submit and the alert appears as expected.

Comment: Ah yeah it does, but it seems buggy. Try clicking submit without first checking a checkbox, it'll return the original error, but not a helpful user one (I hope that makes sense lol)

Comment: Oh I see now. Yeah, it looks like the code you followed also has the same issue. You just don't see it as it has a hardcoded error message rather than it using `errors.message` like you're using.

Comment: Sorry mate, I'm probably being dumb - what's the solution? I've tried `{...register("name", { required: "error message" })}` but it still gives the error

Comment: not too sure tbh. I haven't used yup much before so I'm not that familiar with it. If you want to do something similar to the Stackblitz example you're following you can change `errors && <p className="error">{errors.message}</p>` to be `errors && <p className="error">Some hardcoded error</p>` which is what the Stackblitz example is doing. There might be a way to modify your schema though to stop the error from appearing but I'm not sure how you'd do that.

Comment: Ok mate I got it sorted thanks to you, have a great evening!